# Need to fix timestamps in my TimescaleDB database (the number of seconds provided to TO_TIMESTAMP was incorrect by exactly a factor of 1000)

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timescaledb

I have a TimescaleDB database in which some of the timestamps across several tables are incorrect- I inadvertently gave the TO_TIMESTAMP() function the number of *milliseconds* in Unix time, instead of seconds. Thus, all of these data points are 1000 times longer since 1970 than they should be. I can easily isolate which of these rows need to be fixed with a check for future dates in the where clause, but I am a little stuck on how to convert and replace these incorrect timestamps. I essentially need to get the unix time representation, divide it by 1000, and replace that value in the row, but my SQL is too rusty to piece this query together.

I see that i can use extract(epoch from ) to get the number of seconds, but how to do this to every row and then updating its timestamp is not clear to me.

Edit:

When using the query:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET time = TO_TIMESTAMP(extract(epoch from time) / 1000.0)
WHERE
   time > '2020-01-01 00:00:00';
```

I get the error:

> new row for relation "_hyper_8_295_chunk" violates check constraint
>   "constraint_295"

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd imagine some variation on `UPDATE blah SET blahblah = TO_TIMESTAMP(extract(...) / 1000)` should work.

Comment: I have updated my question to specify this is a timescaleDB database, but when I tried that I get the following error:
new row for relation "_hyper_8_295_chunk" violates check constraint "constraint_295"

Comment: What is the definition of "constraint_295"?

Comment: You can't currently update data in a way that would cause it to "move" between chunks (and when you update them as you put, it would violate "constraints" on the chunk that specify the time range each chunk covers).

Instead, you can execute this as a SELECT, DELETE, INSERT wrapped within a single transaction...

(Timescale person here)

Comment: @jmelesky that's a constraint that TimescaleDB creates to keep data in the right time chunk for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would probably be best to create a new hypertable and run an insert into select from the old hypertable to the new. Or potentially do it in batches. This is because Timescale restricts updating of the partitioning keys so that items don't move between partitions. You can do a delete and then an insert to make that work similarly, but it's going to be more efficient to just create a new hypertable, move everything over with the correct timestamps and then rename than to try doing updates etc.